# React and react native

Tags: reactjs, backend

We want to develop a web and app for our project we want that build the app and web both in react technology.
If we develop the website and mobile app in react then the backend will be the same for both?

Comment: Its simple: Yes!

Comment: you seriously could do a simple google search on this

Comment: A well-designed backend should not care about what frontend you use. That's why APIs exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes backend in any technology will work for both app and website built in react.